# Want to replace the string a number using regex

Tags: json, regex

I have a json string which has the below value

```
"appId": 434832826
```

I want to add double quotes around the number so that the json becomes valid.

I tried `replaceAll(":\\\s\\\d+", ":\"$0\"");`

But it is replacing the value as

```
"appId":": 434832826"
```

I am not sure if this isthe correct regex. An help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Better use appropiate `JSON` functions, depending on the language used.

Comment: I am unable to parse this String to JSON due to errors in the json. So actually speaking I am doing these operations on a String

Comment: so you want to surround `434832826` with `"` marks ?

Comment: Put the number in a capturing group and use this - e.g. `replaceAll(":\\\s*(\\\d+)", ":\"$1\"");`

Comment: Yes exactly I want to do the same

Comment: @Jan Thanks a lot it worked :) Can you please answer it so that I can accept it as answer.

Comment: @SathiyaNarayanan: Glad to be of any help, just answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the number in a capturing group and use the following regex:

```
replaceAll(":\\\s*(\\\d+)", ":\"$1\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jq`:

```
jq '.appId|=tostring' input.json
```

Imagine you have the following json:

```
{
    "appId": 434832826,
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

The above command would produce:

```
{
  "appId": "434832826",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```